# ubuntu 16.04 Kinetic update. no rule to make target libvtkproj

Tags: ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I had my code working. Today I installed the update recommended by Ubuntu which contained some ros-kinetik packages (to be hones I did not checked all of them)
Now, I have a compilation problem.

```
[ 85%] Built target ar_navigation_generate_messages_cpp
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkproj4-6.2.so.6.2.0', needed by 'some_path/ar_navigation/qr_saver'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:10243: recipe for target 'some_path/ar_navigation/CMakeFiles/qr_saver.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [some_path/ar_navigation/CMakeFiles/qr_saver.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The file is there, I don't know what is happening...
Anyone experiencing the same problem?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366812/ubuntu-16.04-kinetic-update.-no-rule-to-make-target-libvtkproj/) by [Bernat Gaston](https://answers.ros.org/users/44457/bernat-gaston/) on ROS Answers with karma: 119 on 2020-12-02

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2020-12-02**:
Glad you were able to work around this problem, but I do want to point out that this is probably not the *right* solution. This is a new issue that was introduced just a few weeks ago that has already been reported in several places. Hopefully a fix will be coming soon. Relevant bug reports:

- https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/issues/318
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vtk6/+bug/1573234
- https://github.com/tfoote/vtk6-release/issues/1

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2020-12-07**:
Fix for issue mentioned above is now released. See my comment to [this answer below](https://answers.ros.org/question/366812/ubuntu-1604-kinetic-update-no-rule-to-make-target-libvtkproj/?answer=366913#post-id-366913).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You shouldn't just create a symlink. Instead, you can do one of the following while we wait for this to be fixed:

- Clone [perception_pcl](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl) into your workspace, *or*:
- Pin the OSRF version of `libvtk6.2` on apt by creating a file called `/etc/apt/preferences.d/ros-pin` with the following content:

  ```
    Package: *
    Pin: origin packages.ros.org
    Pin-Priority: 1000
  ```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2020-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2020-12-07**:
**UPDATE** As mentioned on [this ROS discourse](https://discourse.ros.org/t/new-packages-for-kinetic-kame-2020-12-07/17786) thread, an update to the ROS Kinetic packages that depend on VTK was just released to the package repositories. Users should be able to unpin any pinned packages (e.g. delete file created above), and then run `apt-get` update/upgrade to install the latest packages, and this error should disappear.

**Comment by [dschimpf](https://answers.ros.org/users/52101/dschimpf/) on 2020-12-09**:
@jarvisschultz I ran 'apt-get update/upgrade' and 'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade', deleted the devel and build folder, but I still get the same error: 'make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkproj4-6.2.so.6.2.0', needed by...' In the link you mentioned it says recompile any binaries which are compiled against vtk or pcl. Is that done by deleting the devel and build folder or is there anything else that commonly needs to be rebuilt? Do I need to rebuild pcl for example? Thanks!

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2020-12-10**:
@dschimpf Please see [my comment thread on this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/367010/compiler-error-while-processing-libcostmap_2dso/). Updated versions of the ROS packages that depend on PCL have been released (you shouldn't need to rebuild PCL or `perception-pcl` or any other packages). Just because you ran an update/upgrade doesn't necessarily mean you have all updated packages installed. For example, you could have other conflicting packages causing things to be held back. If you can confirm that you have all versions mentioned in that thread installed, then something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### Second edit: For anyone interested, see the answer of @martin-gunther and specially the comment provided by @jarvisschultz to it.

I edit the answer thanks to @jarvisschultz comment (down). It seems this answer is just a workarround while we wait for the bug to be solved

---

It seems I was able to solve it.
For some reason the symbolic link in

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkproj4-6.2.so.6.2.0
```

Is not there anymore, but there is a library in

```
/usr/lib/libvtkproj4.so
```

So I basically created a link from one to the other and now at least it compiles

```
ln -s /usr/lib/libvtkproj4.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkproj4-6.2.so.6.2.0
```

---

Originally posted by [Bernat Gaston](https://answers.ros.org/users/44457/bernat-gaston/) with karma: 119 on 2020-12-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1